# Please help me LaTex

Tags: technical-drawing

[image]

All Hello?Latex2e system can draw full text of this trigonometric functions using the values?Please help me ... you ...

Comment: This one was probably done with `pstricks`.

Comment: See [TeXample: Unit circle](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/unit-circle/).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Answer (score 14):

[image]

You can fill the missing values in the loop:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\draw (0,0) circle [radius=4cm];
\foreach \Angulo/\Radval/\CosSen/\Posi/\Rot in {%
  0/{0}/{(1,0)}/above/{0}%
  ,30/{\frac{\pi}{6}}/{\bigl(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},\frac{1}{2}\bigr)}/{}/{0}%
  ,45/{\frac{\pi}{4}}/{\bigl(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\bigr)}/{}/{0}%
  ,60/{\frac{\pi}{3}}/{\bigl(\frac{1}{2},\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\bigr)}/{}/{0}%
  ,90/{\frac{\pi}{2}}/{(0,1)}/{right}/{-90}%
  ,120/{\frac{2\pi}{3}}/{\bigl(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\bigr)}/{}/{0}%
  ,135/{\frac{3\pi}{4}}/{\bigl(-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\bigr)}/{}/{0}%
  ,150/{\frac{5\pi}{6}}/{\bigl(-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},\frac{1}{2}\bigr)}/{}/{0}%
  ,150/{\frac{5\pi}{6}}/{\bigl(-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},\frac{1}{2}\bigr)}/{}/{0}%
  ,180/{\pi}/{(-1,0)}/{above}/{0}%
}
{
  \draw[ultra thin] (0,0) -- (\Angulo:4cm)
    node[circle,fill,inner sep=1.75pt,pos=1] {}
    node[pos=0.5,fill=white,sloped,\Posi,rotate=\Rot] {\SI{\Angulo}{\degree}}
    node[pos=0.8,fill=white,sloped,\Posi,rotate=\Rot] {$\Radval$}
    node[pos=1.25,fill=white,sloped,\Posi,rotate=\Rot] {$\CosSen$}
  ;
}
\draw[->] (-5.5,0) -- (5.5,0);
\draw[->] (0,-5.5) -- (0,5.5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This won't help with the axial labels, but this is certainly an appropriate exercise left to the OP :)