# To draw a diagram like this, what code do I need?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

To draw a diagram like this, what code do I need?  help me...What is this.

[image]

Comment: I'll paste a comment left on one of your previous questions: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. [See minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document. `:)`

Comment: You could use something like the `random steps` method shown in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35534/tips-for-creating-semi-random-blob-in-tikz to create the "iceberg".

Comment: I think it is a legitimate question to ask by which means something like the given picture can be drawn. An answer like the one by @TorbjørnT. is helpful to get a starting point; finding it oneself is difficult if one doesn't know what to look for. Therefore I don't think that this question should be closed because of "being unclear".

Comment: @gernot, then the question should be edited to ask "how do I draw the iceberg countour" or something like it. I'd agree too keep it open then, that's surely useful. As it is, I'm mainly basing myself on previous closed questions such as [one asked by the OP himself](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255496/please-help-me-Latex), one could say it has jurisprudence to be closed.

Comment: If you like to draw with help of some LaTeX package, than TikZ and PS trick cross my mind. With some stylization of ice berg and sea this should not be to difficult to draw. However, if you not familiar with this packages, some effort you need to invest to learn how to use selected one.

Comment: Of course this question is posted without previous research, but newbies (including me) questions should be considered positively since everyone has to start learning somewhere, and intuitively it is impossible to start learning with downvoting their questions.

Comment: @DiaaAbidou If you wanted to start learning, would you really start by trying to draw *this*? Surely you'd start with something simpler: a circle, maybe, or a box. The tutorials in the manual are very good then. When you have the basics, then you may get stuck on specific aspects of drawing some particular thing. Then it makes sense to ask. This is just another do-it-for-me.

Comment: @cfr You are right that this question is a do-it-for-me one, but harsh downvoting is something frustrating especially for latex newcomers.

Comment: @DiaaAbidou I did not recommend down-voting it. You recommended considering it positively. I don't know what that means, but it sounds more positive than mere non-down-voting. I don't disagree with down-voting this question (unless it is already down-voted), but I'm not advocating it.

Comment: @DiaaAbidou Also, [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/336218/to-draw-a-graph-like-this-what-code-do-i-need) contains Ti*k*Z code, so it isn't as if this user doesn't know where to start or this is their first attempt at Ti*k*Z. The code isn't attributed, so it is assumed to be the author's. And even if it was attributed, somebody should be able to *begin* by this point. Otherwise, our answers clearly aren't helping at all.

Comment: @cfr I understand your point now.

Answer (score 7):

I probably shouldn't, but as a very simple example.  I only added one of the curved lines on the right though.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\fill [shade,
        top color=white,
        bottom color=blue] (-4,0) rectangle (4,-5);

\draw [decoration={random steps,segment length=0.3cm,amplitude=.1cm},
        decorate,
        rounded corners=.1cm]
     (-3,-4) -- (3,-4) -- (0,2) -- (-3,-4);


\draw [thick,blue] (-4,0) -- (4,0);

\node [above=2mm] at (0,0) {Content};
\node [below=1cm] at (0,0) {Semantic};

\draw [orange] (0.2,2) to[bend left] node[pos=0.5,sloped,below,font=\tiny,black] {WYSIWYG} (1.3,0.1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

To build your figure, you can use, quickly this GUIs,

- `IPE`, http://ipe.otfried.org/;
- `XFig` or `WinFig`, http://winfig.com/;
- `LaTeXdraw`, http://latexdraw.sourceforge.net/
- `InkScape`, https://inkscape.org/en/. With `InkScape` you can create your figure and after you export your picture in `LaTeX`.

Comment: Not only with `InkScape`...

Comment: Definitely. There is also an old program `jpicedt`; also **Adobe Illustrator**, with `pstricks`. I have insert some very easy. Do you know others?